# Conditionally opening Popup Maker popup in wordpress with jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, popup

I am trying to conditionally load a popup in Wordpress. The popup is configured in the plugin [Popup Maker](https://wordpress.org/plugins/popup-maker/) and has a CSS class of "popmake-2503".

I've created a function in my theme's functions.php which loads a script conditionally:

```
// open popup
function open_popup() {
if( is_user_logged_in() && is_page('checkout') )
    {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'open-popup',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/open-popup.js',
array( 'jquery' )
            );
        }
    }
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'open_popup' );
```

In the open-popup.js file, I have the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    alert ('running');
    $('#popmake-2503').popmake('open');
});
```

I have read the [API](https://wppopupmaker.com/docs/developer/overview-popup-maker-javascriptjquery-api/) but still I cant get the popup to fire, and no error shows in the console. The basic javascript alert works.

Thank you.

EDIT1: the other way around works, i.e.,

```
$('#popmake-2503').popmake('close');
```

works for effectively closing the popup after it is automatically loaded (as defined in the Popup Maker configurations in WP admin).

Answer (score 6):

Your solution is correct but currently Popup Maker defers js loading so your code runs before the .popmake('open') function has been loaded and the popups initialized.

We are going to be addressing that soon, but try adding a short timeout before opening it:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#popmake-2503').popmake('open');
    }, 2000);
});
```

or better yet hook into the [`pumInit`](https://github.com/PopupMaker/Popup-Maker/blob/master/assets/js/src/site/plugins/pum.js#L170) event like so. That way it opens as soon as the popup is actually ready. This is also safe to load in the head as it uses .on event binding

```
jQuery(document).on('pumInit', '#popmake-2503', function () {
    PUM.open(2503); // Newer method than $('#popmake-2503').popmake('open'); and uses internal selector caching.
});
```

And lastly if you want a reusable solution you can [create custom conditions](http://docs.wppopupmaker.com/article/132-add-a-custom-popup-condition) that can be used in our popup condition editor. You only need one condition to do both true & false checking. The following doc includes multiple complete examples you can use:

PS I'm the lead developer for PM so this is the defacto best answer ;)

Comment: For me, delay works, listener does not. I don't have skill enough to get why.

Comment: For some strange reason the popup closes itself right after being opened when using the delay method.

Comment: We are using the latest download of Popup Maker (And love it, btw).
For the above event listener method, I don't get the event when we pass in the 2nd argument ('#popmake-2503'). If we target the pumInit event without the explicit ID, it works.

Answer (score 0):

You try to grab popup with id selector `#popmake-2503`, but i your question saw, that it has class `popmake-2503`. So try to change this line:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   alert ('running');
   $('.popmake-2503').popmake('open'); //class selector
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Something has changed, yes. The popup still does not show, but I get the following error from the console: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'meta' of undefined" (which comes from the popup-maker-site.min.js plugin file)...

Comment: As by their API, I believe I really need to use "#" to trigger the popup via jQuery.

Comment: Yes of course if you have an id to your element, better way is to use it for selection. The important thing is to correctly select the item. But because in your question you didn't mention that selected element has an id, instead show class, i decided that you didn't select needed element properly. You may try to debug your code, to be sure that you selected the element properly by placing  `console.log( $('#popmake-2503'), 'test');`. If you can put your code somewhere, I can try to help you more :)

Comment: Thanks. I got the following log from the console: [div#popmake-2503.popmake.theme-2382.responsive.size-medium, context: document, selector: "#popmake-2503"]
0: div#popmake-2503.popmake.theme-2382.active.size-medium.fixed.responsive.custom-position
context: document
length: 1
selector: "#popmake-2503"
__proto__: m[0]

Comment: So the selector was ok. But I managed to solve the issue the other way around (at least for now): the popup opens automatically, but then closes automatically (without user noticing it) if he/she is logged in. Meaning that $('#popmake-2503').popmake('open'); didn't work for opening the popup, but $('#popmake-2503').popmake('close'); worked for closing it.

Comment: Yes,this means your element is selected properly.I can't tell you more without seeing the code,but propose the following: try to add listeners to all events and check if all runs properly: `$('#popmake-2503').on('popmakeBeforeOpen',function(e){console.log(this, 'test');});` for instance.
Also you can only select element without calling 'open', and then play with it in console -check settings, call 'open' there etc. 
Also I don't know if you are tried all reasons from [FAQ](https://wordpress.org/plugins/popup-maker/faq/).And you can put console.logs in `popup-maker-site.js` file itself.

Comment: See my answer to this one for info as to why its not working as well as multiple possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid using jQuery. This allows to disable the plugin when some condition is not true.

```
add_action('wp', 'disablePopup');

function disablePopup () {
    if (/*Some condition is not true*/) return remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'popmake_load_site_scripts');
}
```

Comment: Not recommended at all. Most users do not just have one popup, this would effectively disable all popups at once. The OP seems to have wanted to open one specific popup.